# Bash if file sizes are greater than 1kb

Tags: bash

I have created a `vi` file and I want to check the files in my home directory to see their size. If the size of the regular file is greater than 1kb I want to back it up as a compressed file with .bak extension. I have started with the command `du -h --max-depth=0 * | sort -r` which list the files like...

```
10K archive.tar
1.0K activity48
1.0K activity47
1.0K activity46
1.0K activity45
1.0k activity44
1.0K activity43
1.0K activity42
1.0K activity41
1.0K activity40
1.0K activity39
1.0K activity38
```

These are some of the files listed but my thought is I need to cut field 1 and somehow create an if statement and compare the field something like `if [ $x -ge 1.0 ] ; do` something. Any thoughts on how I should go about the problem...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1k -exec gzip -k -S .bak '{}' \;
```

I'd probably not use a custom extension for the compressed file, though; that's just asking for future confusion.

`find` searches a directory (`.` in this case) for files that pass a filter. Complex filters can be constructed; in this relatively simple case, several primitive filters are chained to select

- Files that are no more than one level deep into `.` (i.e., subdirectories are not searched),
- are regular files,
- 1KB or larger, and
- for which `gzip -k S .bak filename` exits with a status code of `0`.

The `-exec` filter is special in  that it is considered an action (other actions include `-delete` and `-print`). If a filter does not contain an action, an implicit `-print` action is appended to the filter so that the names of all files that fit the filter are printed. Since our filter contains an action, that does not happen.

In any case, we're not really interested in the result of the `-exec` filter in this case, just in its side effect of running the specified command. It is useful to know that `-exec` is also a filter, however, in case you want to chain commands. For example, if you wanted to copy the backup files to another folder after packing them, you could write

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1k -exec gzip -k -S .bak '{}' \; -exec cp '{}.bak' /some/where/else/ \;
```

Then `cp filename.bak /some/where/else/` would be executed only if `gzip -k -S .bak filename` returned with an exit status of `0` (that is, if it indicated successful completion).

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1k -exec gzip {} \;
```

That ought to do it. Well it produces compressed .gz files.